# How to represent the duration of a calendar year in ISO 8601

Tags: date, duration, iso8601

I want to define a calendar year with the ISO 8601 standard. Not a specific year, but the general duration. This has to stand for something that has a duration of exactly one calendar year, that starts on the first of January and ends on December 31.

It is not P1Y, I think, because that could be the duration of a year starting anytime. I can only come up something like: P01/12, but that seems ambiguous or not according to the standard syntax.

Comment: Hmm. One year period is one year period, independent of the data you use as starting value. But it depend on year. You can use P365D (or P366D on certain years). I'm not sure to understand exactly what do you want. Duration in ISO 8601 are not fix

Comment: There is a difference between yearly and a calender year, right? I interpret P1Y as yearly, not specifically starting on January 1st.

Comment: Hmm. There is duration (preceded with P), interval (with a slash, between two ISO dates, one date and a duration, duration and end date, or duration with context), and repeating interval (preceded by R). P1Y is "period of one year" (so as time difference). For *yearly* I would say R/2021/P1Y (so undefined date). I always read *duration* as date differences (so calendar year) and not as repetition (so yearly).

Comment: That makes sense. Then yearly is the more problematic one. Could this also be R/--01-01/P1Y ? (following @ole-v-v)

Comment: I would put a year, any number is ok (the `--` is not more allowed in newest 8601 as far I know). OTOH with `R/../P1Y`, the year is a redundant information. Probably this is also an example in the standard, but standard is very expensive, so who know?

Comment: Yes, the hidden standards. How to reuse them? Thanks for your comments, @giacomo

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
--01-01/P1Y
```

It’s not very clear to me whether it’s valid, but I think it follows the logic of the ISO 8601 standard. it’s a *time interval* that begins on January 1 with no year specified and lasts a year.

A *time interval* is pretty clearly what you are after. According to Wikipedia:

> There are four ways to express a time interval:
>
> 1. Start and end, such as "2007-03-01T13:00:00Z/2008-05-11T15:30:00Z"
> 2. Start and duration, such as "2007-03-01T13:00:00Z/P1Y2M10DT2H30M"
> 3. Duration and end, such as "P1Y2M10DT2H30M/2008-05-11T15:30:00Z"
> 4. Duration only, such as "P1Y2M10DT2H30M", with additional context information

So I have taken number 2. from the list.

Link: Wikipedia article ISO 8601, [section *Time intervals*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals)

Comment: Is "--01-01" not a truncaed expression, that is deprecated?

Comment: Yeah, I wasn’t aware, it seems to have been removed in ISO 8601:2004. Wikipedia does not inform us of a replacement.